# Using SVG Code in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, svg

I am working on one project and getting svg code from server with string and i want to show this svg picture in imageview when the program is running. For example this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
  <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
  <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
</svg>
```

How can i do it. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an other useful way with this library https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp

using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.pixplicity.sharp:library:[VERSION_HERE]'
}
```

using

```
Sharp.loadResource(getResources(), R.raw.cartman)
     .into(mImageView);
```

example here https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp/tree/master/sample-imageview

Comment: there isn't any relational class with SVGImageView in this library.

Comment: Sorry, I use wrong example. I found other more useful way. I editted again answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AndroidSVG, then you can just do something like:

```
SVG svg = SVG.getFromString(mySvgString);
Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture());
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```